# How do I solve the error called " the directory my-app contains files that could conflict (package.json)?

Tags: reactjs

navarajgiri@Navarajs-MacBook-Pro ~ % npx create-react-app my-app
npx: installed 67 in 2.843s
The directory my-app contains files that could conflict:

package.json

Either try using a new directory name, or remove the files listed above.
navarajgiri@Navarajs-MacBook-Pro ~ %

Answer (score 0):

You are in the folder which already has "package.json" which means either:

1. "npm init" was done in the folder or maybe "create-react-app",
2. There's already a react app with folder name "my-app".

Solution - Perform *npx create-react-app* with other name or remove the folder "my-app" and execute the command again

Answer (score 0):

in this directory that you create your app probably you have package.json file that is damaged.

> 1- deleted previous file or directory that contains package.json.
> 2- create a new directory and create your app on it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an issue with older versions of the `create-react-app` command , in my case v1.2.1 and v.1.5.2.

**Solution** :

1. Install the latest versions of create-react-app ( v5.0.0 + , as of today )

**More details** :

After I installed the package using `npm install create-react-app` I got a notification `3 high severity vulnerabilities`. To fix the vulnerabilities I ran `npm audit fix --force` after which `npm list` shows *create-react-app* package version installed to be v1.2.1. Running `npm update create-react-app` updates it only to v1.5.2 and no further.

I reinstalled the *create-react-app* package , without fixing the **security vulnerability** issues this time. The version of the app was v5.0.1 , which had no issues in creating the react project.