# create-react-app without removing existing files

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

i have an existing project folder that contains project assets, some text files, &c. and we're having to use React on this one.  when i run `create-react-app .` or `npx create-react-app <folder>`, it errors out saying i have to remove existing files because 'they might conflict'.  SMH.  how do i override this behaviour and force it to deploy? because i'm not doing this for every project we do...

and, no, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69333199/how-do-i-solve-the-error-called-the-directory-my-app-contains-files-that-could) has nothing useful to offer.

Comment: How about creating the app, then moving the files into their directories?

Comment: because we have hundreds of pre-existing files and other project data that are being used by other team members and other scripts that rely on the path as constituted.  so aside from being a time isssue, it's also an access issue.  it's just irritating and unnecessary to expect that the directory be empty and assume that everything will conflict.  anyway.  if there's something that can be done, great, otherwise, we'll just convince the client to use a less troublesome framework like Vue.

Comment: create-react-app is a generator for "a new single-page application in React." It does not seem designed for your use case.

Comment: @JakeWorth  yeah.  that's what we're learning as we dig into it.  i'm going to let our more hardcore guys deal with that...  just thought there might be a quick fix, as it were.  :D